# Remove gap between two objects

Tags: react-native

I'm creating an app with React Native and I'm using React-Native-Elements(https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/API/searchbar/)

I added search bar to my application, but I have a gap between it and my header.
it looks like this:
[image]

This is my code:

```
render(){
return(
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <SearchBar
    lightTheme
    clearIcon
    returnKeyType="go"
    placeholder='Type Here...'
    textInputRef="search"
    containerStyle={{backgroundColor: "#553A91", }}/>
  </View>
);
}
```

How can I remove the gap?

EDIT:
I tried to use marginTop, it works, but it still a little visible that they are overlap, How can I color the the gap instead?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try by adding `padding:0` to container

Comment: It might be some styling problem (margin/marginTop/padding/paddingTop etc.) with the lib file you are using. Please consider working on simple react-native components specified in the react-native official docs before going on to complex components from libraries. It might give you the exact idea of what is happening while the component is called.

Comment: Thank you both, I will take a look.